# zsh: Change to the directory that a file was copied to within the last command

Tags: zsh

I use `zsh` and have a command

```
> mvcd a b               (and cpcd)
```

as a shortcut for `mv a b` followed by `cd b`. But I'm stupid and very often I just use `mv a b`. 
Is there a command, that I can execute afterward to still go to `b`. Something like:

```
> mv document.pdf ~/Documents
> cdLast     ( <-- this would cd to ~/Documents )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing <kbd>Escape</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> will insert the last argument of the previous command at the cursor. Type `cd`, then press 
<kbd>Escape</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> to insert `~/Document` at the cursor.

Comment: Depending on personal preference, you can also press `Alt`+`.` at the same time.